# Moving some data from one column of MySQL table to another

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I was wondering if there is an easy way of moving some (not all) data from one column to another.

My MySQL table has 200 entries but this is the simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
| ID | A | B |
|  1 |   |   |
|  2 |   |   |
|  3 |   | aa|
|  4 |   | bb|
|  5 |   | cc|
```

So I need to get data from column B to Column A but only the ones that have ID greater than (>) 2. so that aa from 3B will go to 3A, bb from 4B will go to 4A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET
  A=B,
--  B=''
WHERE ID>2
```

Might help. The commented-out line needs to be enabled or disabled, depending on whether you want to **move** or **copy** the values between columns.